# Why does printing a function name returns a value?

Tags: c++

I accidentally printed a function name without the parenthesis and it printed a value. I am just curious about how this happens? 
Output is same irrespective of the function name or definition, and for every time I run it.

EDIT: The answers cleared my doubt, to anyone else who is reading this - 
      Explicitly converting the function name to int works,
      i.e int k=(int)foo;

This test code will make things more clear:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void foo(){cout<<'Á';}      //FUNCTION IS NEVER CALLED

int main()
{
    while(_kbhit())         //JUST TO MAKE SURE BUFFER IS CLEARED
    {   getch();}           //SAME RESULT WITHOUT THESE TWO STATEMENTS

    cout<<foo;              //OUTPUT 1
    printf("\n%u", foo);    //OUTPUT 4199232
    /*int k=foo;            //CANNOT CONVERT VOID(*)() TO 'INT'*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing `cout` and `printf`

Comment: `printf` is not typesafe. Just because `printf` *can* do something, it doesn't mean that it *should*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A mention of a function name without parentheses is interpreted as a function pointer. The pointer is interpreted as an `unsigned int` by the `%u` format specifier, which is undefined behaviour but happens to work on most systems.

The reason `int k = foo` doesn't work is that a function pointer normally needs a cast to be converted to `int`. However, `printf` is much more lenient because it uses `varargs` to parse its argument string; the type of the arguments is assumed to match the type requested in the format string.

Comment: *"A mention of a function name without parentheses is interpreted as a function pointer."* Slightly inaccurate, at least in C++. E.g. `void (&pf)() = foo;`

Comment: "The pointer gets converted to an unsigned int by the %u format specifier." Actually, it would be undefined behaviour, no?

Answer (score 5):

This statement `printf("\n%u", foo);` passes the address of function `foo()` to `printf`. So the value that gets printed is the address of this function in the memory of the running program.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::cout << foo;
```

Outputs `1` because `foo` is a function pointer, it will be converted to `bool` with `std::cout`.

To print its address, you need explicitly cast it:

```
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(foo) << std::endl;
```

---

With `printf("\n%u", foo);`, `%u` expects `unsigned int`, what you saw is the value of the function pointer converted to `unsgigned int`.